# Angular: Showing a fontawesome icon from ngrx

Tags: html, angular, font-awesome, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am saving an icon string like this on my response from API:

```
  {
    "icone": "fas fa-thermometer-half",
    "cor1": "#FFF",
    "cor2": "000"
  }
```

At Angular 10 application I get from NGRX store.

```
  public test$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromTest.getTest))
```

Then I try to render at HTML component.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="test$ | async as tes">
   <i class="{{tes[1].icone}}"></i>
</ngcontainer>
```

The result at html is:

```
<i _ngcontent-yaa-c157="" class="fa-thermometer-half fas"></i>
```

And doenst show...
At NGRX Store I can see the icone string like this: icone:"fas fa-thermometer-half" and I dont know why this change when rendered, but isnt the problem.

Comment: does it work if you put the fas fa-thermometer-half directly in the html? Are you sure the problem is not with the fas icon itself?

Answer (score 0):

Change icon class binding from

```
   <i class="{{tes[1].icone}}"></i>
```

To

```
   <i [ngClass]="{{tes[1].icone}}"></i>
```

Comment: I tried again, after restart the application and I am receiving a new error.

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded!
  - JIT compilation is discouraged for production use-cases! Consider AOT mode instead.
  - Did you bootstrap using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or '@angular/platform-server'?
  - Alternatively provide the compiler with 'import "@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping.
Error: Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded!
`

Comment: Fixed the error, same problem when i try with [ngClass].. doenst render the icon.
<i class="fa-thermometer-half fas"></i>
Works well, but not when i use the string from ngrx or component instead.

Comment: Put yours store request on AfterViewInit hook